# How to make session data in http-kit

Tags: clojure, session-variables, http-kit

For my login system, I need to implement session data for different functionality when users are logged in or not.

I've only ever done sessions in `flask`, and google searches don't reveal a lot (or, more likely, I'm searching the wrong things). I have two questions:

1. Is there a canonical way to do session data in Clojure and can this specifically done in `http-kit`?
2. Is an atom enough, or would this be bad practice?

Comment: IDK about http-kit but you can definitely do sessions in ring https://ring-clojure.github.io/ring/ring.middleware.session.html

Answer (score 0):

`session`s will have to be managed via `ring`. `http-kit` is a server & will only use the `ring` spec for requests and responses.

To fetch the session

```clj
(get-in req [:session :auth-token])
```

To add a session to your ring response

```clj
(assoc res
       :session {:auth-token auth-token
                 :userid (:id json-data)
                 :username (:username json-data)})
```